# Behaviour of RETURN parameter of BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, bapi

I am using `bapi_goodsmvt_create` to post in `migo` transaction code.

The parameter `return` is not returning any value when the postings are successful.

Is `return` supposed to return only error messages? Or both error and success messages?

Answer (score 3):

That is exactly how it works, if there are no errors, the *RETURN* table will be empty. The FM BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE is well documented:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is how BAPIs behave in general, by the way.